# How to add bubble counter on tabs in an Android application?

Tags: android

How to add bubble counter on tabs in an Android application? Same has been done by eBuddy Android application.

Comment: The badge widget for displaying counter.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean a 'badge' widget, there is no built in mechanics for this in android.
you have to design your own TabHost widget which displays the 'bubble' the way you want.

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about red badge widget for displaying counter. I am looking for sample code to implement this.